# sort dataset array by value[1]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

How can I sort this dataset by its value [1] (4,10,19) so it returns as A,C,B?

```
var dataset = [
        ["A","4","570"],
        ["B","19","123"],
        ["C","10","395"],
    ];
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/2js5x/

Comment: You want to sort only on the second position, "data-bar-1", is that right?

Comment: yep. in a further step I might try the sum of data-bar-1 + data-bar-2

Comment: So I think that http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp is powerful enought: just define a sort function that compares the [1] of each operand

Answer (score 1):

Here you are sir
http://jsfiddle.net/2js5x/1/
just using custom sort :)

```
function on_first(a,b){
    return a[1]-b[1]; 
}
```

You may evolve the custom sort to do the sum, else...